# Giving permissions to a folder

Tags: linux

I need to give permission for a particular folder for a specific user. I executed this command below, and checked with the user but still he is unable to access it.

What is wrong with this command?

`sudo chmod -R ugo+rw logs`

Comment: What is the ownership like? If you do an `ls -laht`, what does the line with that file show? What is the username?

Answer (score 2):

That should be simple:

```
sudo chown user_name folder
```

Then

```
sudo chown -R user_name folder
```

execute the commands one after another to give the right permissions.